# Manually log in-app purchase events in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to send in-app purchase events to Firebase manually ? (instead of letting Firebase tracking them automatically?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have [ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE) event. I suppose that's what you should use in order to track any purchases that aren't tracked automatically. Pass this constant as the event name to `logEvent` call.